# Brackets Git: how to go back to last commit

Tags: git, version-control, adobe-brackets

I'm new to git and using Brackets (Mac) as my main editor. There is a nice brackets git extension. I installed the extension successfully. But – how – can I return / revert / go back / to a commit in history? There is no Button for sth. like this at all. A friend of mine, using git for years on ubuntu, failed as well. 
As I am new to git I do not even know what the right terminology is for what I want to do. So maybe its all about my low understanding of git itself. (The setup is not complicated: I work alone, on local machine).

Would be very thankful for replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return to a history commit in git log, you can do it via terminal or [git bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) (git command line).

First you can click **show history**, then the commit history will listed from new to old. Find the commit you want to return.

Then click **open bash/terminal console**, and use the command `git checkout <commit>`. Then the `HEAD` will point to commit you specified.

[image]

[image]

If you want to go back to the latest commit, you can use `git checkout branchname`.

Comment: Thanks! It works and I guess I got it. Made my day, srsly!

Answer (score -1):

The Brackets-Git extension supports both resetting to an earlier commit and checking-out an earlier commit (without having to use the Git Bash terminal).

These are accessed from the commit history: click the little clock button to open the commit history and then select the commit you want to go back to. At the top you will now have two buttons Reset Index and Check out. If you want to go back one commit, just select the second one down in the list at the bottom.

[Reset and Checkout buttons in Brackets-Git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NNSm.png)

Using Reset will take you back to the commit you selected (note if you do a hard reset you will lose any uncommitted changes).

If you use checkout it will open the selected commit as if it were a branch (it will appear in the branch are of the left brackets pane - where the files are); again you will lose any uncommitted changes.

If you are not sure of the differences between checkout and reset use checkout (it's easier to get back to where you were: just switch back to your latest branch). The link below explains, with a fully worked example, how to use each; it also highlights the deficiencies and peculiarities of each approach.

One thing to be aware of, the reset and checkout buttons are only visible if you have enabled the advanced features of Brackets-Git (these are on the settings page - File - Git Settings, Features Tab - tick "Enable Advanced Features").

There is a fairly comprehensive explanation of how to enable these functions  and how to use each of them (with pictures); you can find it on this website:

http://practicalseries.com/1002-vcs/07-00-regression.html

N.B. The website is a fairly good tutorial for using the Brackets-Git extension.